Can we add a button inisde SharePoint List view to move folder using power automate flow
We have 2 libraries inside the same site:-

Sales

Account


now inside the Sales we create prospect folders and which only allow account managers to access and view, then once we hire a prospect its folder should be moved to the Account library and permission should be set on its sub-folders. so the built-in Move-To button will not allow use to set custom permission settings. to do so, we are thinking if there is a way to select a folder >> click on a button >> this button will pass the folder ID to a power automate flow, and then the power automate flow will do the move the permission reset.. is this something we can achieve in power automate and sharepoint UI?

Thanks

Here are steps for you refer to:
1.Create a flow to move folder and reset folder permissions.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/restore-SharePoint-parent-permissions/td-p/482117
https://tomriha.com/how-to-restore-sharepoint-item-file-permissions-with-power-automate/
2.Use JSON formatting to create buttons that start a flow on the corresponding list item in the SharePoint.
https://www.benprins.net/2020/02/20/flow-button-to-launch-a-flow-from-a-view/#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20column%20formatting%20%28JSON%29%20to%20create,be%20displayed%20and%20you%20can%20start%20the%20Flow.
